# I have installed Pandas, however it keep saying no module named pandas when I run the program. how to solve this problem, please tell me the detail

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed pandas, it keep saying no module named pandas when I run the program. please tell me how to solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjkTs.jpg)

```
C:\Users\philh\anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.8.5-h5fd99cc_1\pythonw.exe C:/Users/philh/PycharmProjects/pythonProject202308/meanreversion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/philh/PycharmProjects/pythonProject202308/meanreversion.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Process finished with exit code 1

C:\Users\philh\PycharmProjects>pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (10.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in c:\users\philh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.3; python_version < "3.10" in c:\users\philh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.24.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\philh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\philh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\philh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
Successfully installed pandas-2.0.3
```

Comment: `python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: make sure you install pandas in the same python that you are running your program with.

Comment: You have two (or more) installations of python on your computer.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show pandas` and also this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 2):

It is important to be specific in your questions and say what you have tried because it can be lots of problems. But I'll suggest this

[image: Pycharm environment]

I saw that you're using pycharm. So, first click on (venv). After that, click on interpreter settings.

After that, click on "+" sign and look for 'pandas' and install it.

Close the current window. Click 'ok' and get back to your code and try to import again.

It should fix your problem.